# Spring Boot - Enums when to use?

Tags: json, spring-boot, enums, spring-data-jpa

I have a User Entity that has Nationality and Gender as properties.
What is the best pratice?
Use Enums for that or have a separated table?

I also plan to send all the Nationalities and Genders back to the frontend as json data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to do a new build and deploy to add a gender or nationality, then use a separate table, otherwise use an enum.

For nationality you can define an enum with a "nationality" property, e.g.
ZA("South African"). The property can then contain spaces and accents.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using enums if the properties are not frequently updated

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But for example, my nationalities name have accents and space between words. How can I maintain the same structure using enums?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally start with an enum if I find that I'm updating it too often or need other people to update it that would be a good time to transition it to a table.